# AdminSettings API using service account auth/keyword failures

Tags: python-2.7, google-admin-sdk, google-admin-settings-api

Trying to retreive domain number of users, 'GetCurrentNumberOfUsers()', using AdminSettings API via a Service Account in **Python**. Enabled delegation wide authority and scope, but getting errors.  I have used service account for Calendar API, Directory API, EmailSettings API, but not working for AdminSettings.  Tried sample code at: *github.com/Khan/gdata-python-client/blob/master/samples/apps/adminsettings_example.py* but get 'Authorization required' error while using correct credentials for admin account: [API Client Acccess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7pxZ.jpg)

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
import gdata.gauth
import gdata.apps.service
import gdata.apps.adminsettings.service

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX-ebirq08jvhldahbb482u8a1otu9n3l8p.apps.googleusercontent.com"
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = 'gapi_admin/privatekey.p12'
f = file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, key, scope='https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/', sub='admin@xxxtestmail.edu')
auth2token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)
service = gdata.apps.adminsettings.service.AdminSettingsService(source="testApp", domain='xxxtestmail.edu')
service = auth2token.authorize(service)

print service.GetCurrentNumberOfUsers()

#output
#TypeError: new_request() takes exactly 1 non-keyword argument (2 given)
```

works fine in OAuth2 Playground, view [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IncXF.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old GData Python library service objects don't actually support OAuth 2.0 which is what you need to be using. However you can hack a access token on there. Try something like:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, key, scope='https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/', sub='admin@xxxtestmail.edu')
credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())
service = gdata.apps.adminsettings.service.AdminSettingsService(source="testApp", domain='xxxtestmail.edu')
service.additional_headers[u'Authorization'] = u'Bearer {0}'.format(credentials.access_token)

print service.GetCurrentNumberOfUsers()
```

Comment: I get '**Bearer None**' returned. Works fine in Playgroud. I'm including a link to a Screenshot at http://postimg.org/image/kcr73m7y9/ of OAuth playground results vs code execution. More help please?

Comment: forgot one step to refresh credentials so access token is populated. Try now.

Comment: Jay, you have been most helpful! It works now!! I hope others can benefit from your help and this work. Here is a screenshot of the result http://postimg.org/image/e5i8wnpid/.

Comment: Is there any way to perform this in .Net? There's no such AdminSettingsService in any NuGet package. I can get a token after having sent the JWT assertion but any call to the API returns a 403 error: "You are not authorized to perform operations on the domain xxx". However, I'm not able to include the "sub" in JWT as I always get a Bad Request exception while inserting it.

Comment: .Net is an entirely different beast and deserves its own question.

Comment: OK, just a last thing: I installed GAM trying to sniff with Fiddler how HTTP requests are made so that I can create them from my .Net app. So I used proxy settings to redirect data to Fiddler successfully but I face a SSL certificate issue which is logical as https only is used. Is there any way to disable certificate verification to make the sniff possible or is this a dead end? I'll create a separate question after that if necessary.

Comment: No need to sniff traffic with GAM, just create a file called debug.gam in the same folder as gam.py or gam.exe and GAM will gladly print out all the traffic and headers it sends.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very useful trick. I used the same headers with no success but if I use your OAuth token, I get a valid answer. So, I suppose I cannot achieve this with a Service Account token, you probably use the Oauth client token for this API. I wasn't able to get debug traces for the 'oauth create' command to validate this but I suppose it's deliberate for security purposes. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: This is going way off topic from original question. You should start a new question.

Comment: Done it there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35848587/adminsettings-api-using-service-account-in-a-c-sharp-console-application.